# File IO operations not working when broadFileSystemAccess capability declared

Tags: file-io, uwp, windows-10-universal

I had faced some strange behavior while using "broadFileSystemAccess" capability during my app development, i.e.

I'm using above mentioned capability to access entire file system and my app's both min and max version I kept **ver 17134 (RS4)**, and below API's are throwing access denied exceptions in spite of declaring `broadFileSystemAccess` capability.

The API's are listed below:

- `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` - From `System.IO` namespace

  Refer https://github.com/siddhu10/Zipping.git for a sample example which fails for above API.
- `DownloadFileAsync` from FluentFTP - 3rd party lib from nuget

  Refer https://github.com/siddhu10/FileTransfer.git for a sample example which fails for above API.

**Imp Note:** The observation is above API's fail only when min ver is also 17134 (RS4) and higher versions. These API's work when min version is kept 15063 and lower versions.

Kindly help resolving above issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way .NET handles brokered file paths changed in RS3 as part of the .NET Standard work. Prior to RS3, the `System.IO` types would try to use the WinRT APIs under the covers to access brokered files, which worked as long as the user had granted the app access.

Starting in RS3, the APIs changed to just use the raw Win32 APIs (as part of the standardization effort). There are now Win32 APIs that can access brokered locations, but due to a sequence of unfortunate events these aren't the APIs .NET is using.

As long as your min-ver is less than RS3, you'll get the older behavior (but not full .NET Standard 2.0 support).

As of now, the only way to access brokered locations if your min-ver is RS3 or higher is via WinRT APIs or Win32 `FromApp` APIs. And since `broadFilesystemAccess` is in RS4, I'm afraid you can't use it with the `System.IO` APIs.

If you need to use .NET APIs then you will need to set the minver to RS2 or lower and then ask the user to pick a folder with the `FolderPicker`. You can then use the `FutureAccessList` to ensure you have ongoing access to the location.

Comment: Wow! Had no idea about this, thank you for the detailed explanation! Even though I understand the standardization is a good thing however, it seems like the old behavior was a bit more useful. It would be great if UWP allowed `System.IO` to take `broadFilesystemAccess` into consideration in the future.

Comment: As I chose "broadFilesystemAccess" capability which starts from RS4 i wanted to restrict the installation of app and so kept min ver also as 17134. Now can you suggest any alternatives to achieve the zip creation and FTP download operations (OR) i will use min ver as 15063 and lower, in this case suggest how to restrict installations from RS3 and lower? Could you please suggest me which way is possible and how to achieve it?

Comment: But if I use "FolderPicker" instead of "broadFilesystemAccess" the FTP library download api expects a string type path and not a storage folder or storage file type. If i use Path property of the StorageFolder again I would get the access denied exception as i access direct path, and my download api fails. How to fix this?

Comment: The FTP libarry i'm using is FluentFTP and I get to see their code and it uses System.IO namespace and so I got such exceptions. I would like to know whether any FTP library will be available that uses ONLY WinRT compatible API's?

Comment: That I don't know, sorry.

Comment: Hi Peter, even with min ver > RS3 and using Win32 APIs from a C++ WinRT library, I can't access c:\ with broadFileSystemAccess. Is this an intended behavior? Is there a way to access all user-files using C++-Win32 in WinRT library?

Comment: Did you use the `FromApp` APIs? And did you check if the capability is enabled for your app in Settings? This is RS4, right?

Comment: this is unsatisfying, the System.io.directory.getfiles although only returned name strings it was in fact many times faster than the wholesome Windows.storage Query implementation that returns storageitems. last time i checked, it takes  up to 4-5 seconds to do a simple 1k file enumeration on a dual core cpu and it wont even scale well or smoothly with multithreading

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability applies only to the new `Windows.Storage` APIs in UWP. The classic File IO API you are using are not allowed to access.

You can verify this in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capability-list). This means you will either have to replace the code with alternatives that use the new APIs or copy the files you need to use to a location that is accessible to the classic APIs like `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`.

Comment: But same capability, it is working with min ver 15063. why it is not when i set min ver also 17134?

Comment: That is very unusual, as according to docs it should fail everywhere, especially when you run the 17134 on your machine, it should use the latest API in any case... Could you post some of the source code?

Comment: Or even better - could you post some simple app that shows this behavior on GitHub? I would verify it in my machine

Comment: I already added the github links in my question above for both scenarios. In those samples min ver is set as 17134 and it does fail that time. But you can try changing min ver to 15063 and you can see it working. Kindly help with the solution

Comment: I will definitely check it out once I get home, thank you!

Comment: See my answer. It's complicated. Unless I've forgotten something :) (away from PC...)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the conclusion here is that .Net Standard file access model (System.IO namespace) is completely broken for UWP apps and there is absolutely no way to make it work. I hoped that broadFileSystemAccess would fix that, unfortunately that is not the case. Hope this will be fixed soon.